# Data from firebase don't load?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data of a certain userId out of a firebase Database. But nothing happens? I am creating an AngularFireObject of typ Profile

like this:

```
  profileData: AngularFireObject<Profile>;
```

There is no error in the code. the HTML is shown how i prefer it but without the data.
the only thing what isn't correct, is that the Methode ionViewDidLoad is shown as unused. But when i pass the code inside the constructor it doesn't has any effect.

Can someone help me with that? Thanks a lot!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {Profile} from '../../shared/models/profile';


/**
 * Generated class for the HomePage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {

  profileData: AngularFireObject<Profile>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, private toast: ToastController,
              public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) { }
ionViewDidLoad() {
 this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.uid);
      if (data && data.email && data.uid) {
        console.log(data.email);
        console.log(data.uid);

        this.toast.create({
          message: `Welcome to The APP, ${data.email}`,
          duration: 5000
        }).present();

        this.profileData = this.afDatabase.object(`/profile/${data.uid}`)

        console.log(this.profileData);

      } else {
        this.toast.create({
          message: `Could not find authentication details`,
          duration: 3000
        }).present();
      }
    })
  }
}
```

This is the HTML where i would like to load the data.

profile.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {Profile} from '../../shared/models/profile';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class ProfilePage {

  profile = {} as Profile;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase,
    public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  /*ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProfilePage');
  }*/

  createProfile(){
    this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
      this.afDatabase.object(`profile/${auth.uid}`).set(this.profile)
      .then(() => this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage'))

    })
  }

}




 <p>Username: {{(profile | async)?.username }}</p>
  <p>First Name: {{(profile | async) ?.lastName }}</p>
  <p>Last Name: {{(profile | async) ?.firstName}}</p>
```

[image: Console.log]

Answer (score 1):

There is a issue in the path. your path has a userid which concatenated with profile without separating it using **slash** (/)

Try to re correct path,

```
this.afDatabase.object(`/profile/${data.uid}`)
```

To retrieve data and view, do this way

```
 this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if (data && data.email && data.uid) {
        this.afDatabase.database.ref().child(`/profile/${data.uid}`).once('value', (snapshot) => {
          let result = snapshot.val();
          for (let k in result) {
            this.profileData = result[k];
          }
        });
      }
 });
```

**This is the html **

```
  <p>Username: {{ profileData.username }}</p>
  <p>First Name: {{ profileData.lastName }}</p>
  <p>Last Name: {{( profileData.firstName}}</p>
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer i correct it but it has no effect

Comment: `           message: `Welcome to The APP, ${data.email}`,
 ` this message pops up but the data doesn't get loaded

Comment: did you console.log data.email & data.uid? tell me the results after that

Comment: can you help me with that? how do i log that? i am totally new to that topic

Comment: what do you need from the log file? because when i log data.email and data.uid it gives me only the login email address and the uid?

Comment: i changed the HTML Coe to `code <p>Username: {{(profileData | async)?.username }}</p> ` i get an InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: sorry for late to reply.. you can follow this tutorial to learn console logging.." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1o17_2YLfI " you check first you getting value correct values first or not. console log and see whether you getting uid. this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => { console.log(data.uid); });  after console the reuslt of profileData, console.log(profileData); you can see the result on developer tools on the browser.

Comment: can you edit you question and put your whole code of ts file? so I can help you with another option

Comment: i edited the code and made a log. the this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => { console.log(data.uid); }) gave me back my uid and the console.log(profileData) (image in the body)

Comment: I have Edited the Post and try it .. let me know if does not work

Comment: in the html it is an error: username is not defined AngularFireObject does not contain such a member

Comment: can you edit code and put your database structure and profile.ts file? t

Comment: what do you mean with database structure? i added profile.ts

Comment: @RahulRaj happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

in Homepage.ts 
you only have to add take(1) in ligne 27 just like that :
 this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data => {